# Запись массивов в json на c#

Tags: c#, массивы, json

Возник вопрос, ответ на который я затрудняюсь найти.
Необходимо в Json записать таблицы с цифрами (массивы). Эти таблицы отсортированы по соответствующим характеристикам. На выходе хочу получить подобную иерархию в Json:

```
Параметр 1:(для выбора необходимой таблицы) 
   Параметр 1.1:(для выбора необходимой таблицы) 
      Параметр 1.1.1: (название i-ой строки из таблицы) 
         ключ = значение (значение элемента из j-ой колонки данной строки) 
         ключ = значение 
         ... 
      Параметр 1.1.2:
         ключ = значение
         ...
   Параметр 1.2:
      Параметр 1.2.1: 
         ключ = значение
         ... 
Параметр 2: и т.п.
```

Может объяснение корявое, заранее извините, но лучше не осилил...

Comment: Тут ведь дело не в JSON, ибо JSON - это зеркальная копия того, что вы ему даете. Собственно, создайте такую структуру классов, которую вы описали, заполните ее и потом сериализируйте.

Comment: Возможно. Тогда проблема в создании такой структуры. Вернее в четком понимании как её создать.

Comment: Ну, если "Параметр ..." - это некий ключ, то вам нужен словарь, если это строгое наименование переменной, то класс. `ключ = значение` - это свойство. Ну а дальше делаете матрешку из классов/словарей, внутри который класс со свойствами.

Comment: Что нибудь для примера бы) для наглядного понимания. А то я в Json  сразу с головой решил нырнуть)

Comment: Чтобы разобраться, вашего абстрактного примера недостаточно, нужна конкретика. То что вы показали, можно сделать разными способами. А пока непонятно, чем параметр отличается от ключа, фиксированный или динамический набор ключей, есть ли чистые безключевые коллекции и т.д. Как сказано выше, для начала создайте объектную модель данных. Сериализовать данные в объектах в JSON проще простого.